# How to add a unique icon to each list item with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, font-awesome

I have a list on my website, and each list item has a unique class name. Now I would like to assign a certain font-awesome icon to each class. Here is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3"></li>
    <li class="item-4"></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is using javascript, write some code to assign a font awesome icon to each unique class, so that it would end up looking like this:

```
<ul>
    <i class="far fa-route"></i><li class="item-1"></li>
    <i class="far fa-map"></i><li class="item-2"></li>
    <i class="far fa-clock"></i><li class="item-3"></li>
    <i class="far fa-calendar"></i><li class="item-4"></li>
</ul>
```

So as you can see, I would like to give each unique class a different icon. How would I go about doing this? Also I am very new to javascript so please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319682/jquery-append-icons-generated-by-for-loop-into-list-items-anchor

Comment: Are you sure, you want to insert `<i>` before `<li>` tag? I think you should to append '<i>' tag to `<li>` tag, like this: `<li class="item-.."><i class="far fa-.."></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Create the array of font-awesome classes. Get all the `lis` and then you can use `insertBefore` on it.

```js
const awesomeIcons = ["fa-route", "fa-map", "fa-clock", "fa-calendar"];

const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const lis = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

const newlis = [...lis].forEach((li, idx) => {
  const i = document.createElement('i');
  i.className = "far " + awesomeIcons[idx];
  ul.insertBefore(i, li);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item-1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item-2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item-3">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item-4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```